# Convert String Color ("0x5b9f18") to hexcolor in Java

Tags: java

public class Hexcolor {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a="0x5b9f18";
    String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", a);
    System.out.println(hexColor);
}
```

}

Error Message

Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at Hexcolor.main(Hexcolor.java:6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking for...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 0x5b9f18;
  String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", a);
  System.out.println(hexColor);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String a="0x5b9f18";
   String hexColor = "#" + a.substring(2);
   System.out.println(hexColor);
}
```